Angular Ngrx Store and APP_Initialiser
Hi I really am struggling with an issue.
We currently are using nrgx Store to essentially store data client side regarding information about the client side application. This is working great.
However we are finding that when users are navigate off the site then back onto it it is remembering previous data.
Therefore I'm trying to reset the store information on application start using an APP_INITALIZER.
My problem is that the intializer is async an therefore my calls to reset the ngrx store are starting but not finishing before the application is fully initialized.
Here is what i have:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { ResetApplicationStateModel } from 'src/app/modules/state/application-state.actions';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppStateInitializerService {

isDevelopment = !environment.production;

constructor(private store: Store) {}

async initialize(): Promise<void> {
let loggingPrefix = 'app-state-initialiser.service::initializeApp - ';

return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
  if (this.isDevelopment) {
      console.log(loggingPrefix + 'start of method');
  }

  //do your initialisation stuff here  
  try {  
      // Wait for the action to complete
      if (this.isDevelopment) {
        console.log(loggingPrefix + 'before ResetApplicationStateModel');
      }
      
      this.store.dispatch(new ResetApplicationStateModel());
      if (this.isDevelopment) {
        console.log(loggingPrefix + 'after ResetApplicationStateModel');
      }
      
      if (this.isDevelopment) {
        console.log(loggingPrefix + 'end of method');
      } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(loggingPrefix + 'Action failed:', error);
  }

  // Set the wait loop 
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.isDevelopment) {
      console.log(loggingPrefix + 'end of method');
  }
      resolve();
  }, 1000);
});
}
}

And in the app.module.ts
export function initializerStateService(myInitializerService: 
AppStateInitializerService) {
return (): Promise<any> => { 
  return myInitializerService.initialize();
}
}

Can anyone help?

Single page applications usually do not do well with back button, since the previous state get's loaded, sometimes the page doesn't work at all. Would suggest the below fix to solve the issue.

In you root component app.component.ts place this hostListener. We can do two methods to fix this issue.
We can reload the entire page to prevent the state from being stored. On refresh the state is reset to the initial value. (prefer this method since it's easier to maintain and prevents the user from using the back button often).
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
  location.reload()
}

If you do not like the concept of reload, you can write a method that resets the service properties, so that they are restored to their initial state.
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
  location.reload()
}


Then in the service you can write the method that resets these variables.
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
  this.ngrxService.reset();
}

Service:
@Injectable({ ... })
export class ngrxService {
  reset() {
    // reset the state properties to the initial values.
  }
}


First thing - NgRx by default does not persist the state. I would start by checking for such implementation, if it's not required, then block it. Look for meta reducers, or library like ngrx-store-localstorage.
If you are using Redux DevTools, such feature can be toggled on there. Also worth checking, if that's not the cause. It won't happen in the production though.
If that fails, you can still use APP_INITIALIZER. You just need to wait for the confirmation from the NgRx that the state was flushed. So together with the action dispatch, you should also introduce selector to the APP_INIT function and let it resolve the promise.
Something like this:
import { take, firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

async function initialize(): Promise<void> {
  let loggingPrefix = "app-state-initialiser.service::initializeApp - ";

  this.store.dispatch(new ResetApplicationStateModel());

  const selector$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(SelectResetConfirmation), // Custom selector - checks if state is clean
    take(1) // Way to unsubscribe, just to be sure
  )
  await firstValueFrom(selector$); // And this resolves the promise, when selector emits
}

EDIT: Extended answer
Thinking about it, you can use an effect which will trigger confirmation action. Something like this:
// Effect
@Effect()
resetState$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ResetApplicationStateModel), // Provide correct type
    map(() => new ConfirmStoreReset()) // Dispatch a new action and have a reducer ready
  ) 
);

// Reducer
export const yourState = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(ConfirmStoreReset, state => ({ ...state, stateReset: true})), // Initial value - false
  //...
);

// Selector
export const SelectResetConfirmation = (state: AppState) => state.stateReset;

Now you can have a simple selector, which returns value of stateReset property. Just makes sure the code matches your NgRx version, there might be slight differences. But you should get the idea

Are you able to give me an example of how to write the Custom Selector?
